# debo realizar este código, y he intentado de todo con el ciclo while, pero se me genera un bucle infinito

Tags: python, while

Crea programa en Python que solicite al usuario:

1. Ingresar un número entero cualquiera del 1 al 9.
2. Luego solicitar que ingrese números secuenciales partiendo por 1,
3. pero saltándose aquellos que sean múltiplos del valor ingresado al comienzo.
4. En caso de ingresar un valor erróneo,
5. enviar un mensaje indicando el error y
6. El número que correspondía ingresar

```
print("ingrese un numero del 1 al 9")
print("¿con que numero desea jugar?:")
n1=int(input())
n2=int(input("ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer 
 numero ingresado:"))


while True:
   if not n1%n2==0:
       print("ingrese un número que no sea múltiplo de",n1)
   if n1%n2!=0:
       continue
       print("perdiste")
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento.

Comment: Buen día, el formato del código estaba mal y ahora ya se ve correctamente en la pregunta pero la indentación no era clara así que no sé si los dos `if` los pusiste en el mismo nivel, podrías revisar y aclarar si se muestra tal como lo tienes en tu programa?

Comment: El problema está en las condiciones, ambas condiciones son iguales, es decir, las dos evalúan que n1%n2 sea diferente que `0`

Comment: while True:
    if not n1%n2==0:
        print("ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo de",n1)
    if n1%n2==0:
        print("perdiste")    #modifiqué las condiciones, pero de igual forma, se realiza la acción de forma infinita. necesito que si el numero es multiplo, arrojé el mensaje "perdiste" y si no es multiplo, me sigá pidiendo insertar un numero

Comment: hay varias cosas para que vayas cambiando: 1)el ciclo no termina porque no hay una condición para ello, por ejemplo si pierde se necesita un break, pero si va bien se necesita un límite de ingresos 2)dentro del ciclo en lugar de print necesitas input() 3)el input devuelve cadenas, así que debes convertirlo a entero para ello la dunción int() 4)ya podrías mejorar tu código y en caso de que aún no funcione publicas el que ya modificaste.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
print("ingrese un numero del 1 al 9")
n1 = int(input("¿con que numero desea jugar?:"))

while True:
    n2 = int(input("ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer numero ingresado:"))

    if n2 % n1 == 0:
       print("perdiste")
       break
```

Dentro del ciclo tienes que pedir un número y confrontarlo con el número base. La prueba a hacer es `n2 % n1`, pues se supone que `n2` debe ser mayor que `n1`. La comparación original no funciona; siempre arroja un resto.

#### Demo

El código produce:

```
ingrese un numero del 1 al 9
¿con que numero desea jugar?:4
ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer numero ingresado:5
ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer numero ingresado:6
ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer numero ingresado:7
ingrese un numero que no sea multiplo del primer numero ingresado:8
perdiste

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: falta según el planteo, que debe iniciar el ingreso desde el 1 y al perder mostrar el valor que correspondía ingresar

Comment: @tincopasan. La pregunta era "cómo salir del ciclo infinito", no "¿me hacen la tarea?"

Comment: pues en los comentarios ya estaba esa respuesta, sin escribir el código

Comment: @tincopasan. Respondi a la pregunta, no a los comentarios.